# scala enclose a map to a struct?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a schema and called a udf on this column called referencesTypes

```
 |-- referenceTypes: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- map: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

The udf

```
val mapfilter = udf[Map[String,Long],Map[String,Long]](map => {
map.keySet.exists(_ != "Family")
val newMap = map.updated("Family",1L)
 newMap
})
```

Now after the udf is used my schema goes to this

```
|-- referenceTypes: map (nullable = true)
|    |-- key: string
|    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = false)
```

What do i do to get back referenceType as Struct and map as subroot. In other words how do i convert it back to the orginal on the top with Struct and map one level below.. Bottom has to look like top again, but dont know what changes to make to the udf.

Tried toArray(thought it can be struct) and tomap as well?

basically need to bring back `[]`

actual : `Map(Family -> 1)`

EXPECTED : `[Map(Family -> 1)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `struct`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

df.withColumn(
  "referenceTypes",
  struct(mapFilter($"referenceTypes.map").alias("map")))
```

Comment: `|-- referenceTypes: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- col1: map (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = false)`

awesome but how to change col1: to map?